# Why might we reference $scope.model in angular code?

Tags: angularjs, model, angularjs-scope

I'm working on some code that references $scope.model. So my understanding is that in angular the $scope essentially represents the model anyway.

In the code I'm working on certain properties have been added to a $scope.model. So is adding members under $scope.model a recognised (or sensible) angular practice (since 'model' seems to essentially be an arbitrary member that someone has simply decided to add to the scope). If using a $scope.model is a useful practice, when should it be used? There don't seem to be online resources that mention $scope.model.

Answer (score 1):

actually every controller had associated $scope object (contain some properties) when you use $scope.model you are setting a model property or a function behaviour and make it available to the view (among other $scope properties in most cases you dont have to worry about them)

you can learn more about the $scope and it properties and life cycle in angularJS documentation its a usefull resource 
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope

Comment: Thanks Eng, although I'm pretty sure the $scope.model in the code I'm working on is simply adding a custom 'model' member since the $scope itself is the model, so we don't need to use $scope.model. I think it's been done for some kind of arbitrary separation of some properties into a '$scope.model' member.